# Collision of a ball with wedge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

**Question:-** A ball of mass $m$ with velocity $u_{0}$ collides perpendicularly with smooth wedge of mass $M$. Taking coefficient of restitution as $e$. Find velocity gained by wedge after collision.

[image]

Let velocity of ball after collision be $v_{2}$(perpendicular to wedge) and velocity of wedge after collision be $v_{1}$

Applying Conservation of momentum along $x$-axis

$mu_{0}sin\alpha=Mv_{1}-mv_{2}sin\alpha$

If we apply conservation of momentum along $y$-axis we get $u_{0}=v_{2}$ which would imply elastic collision and that is wrong.

I have learnt that we can neglect gravitational forces during collision due to small impact time ($\Delta T\to 0$)which leads to no change in momentum as $\Delta P=F \Delta T$.So what's goes wrong here in this case

Thank You in advance!

Comment: I have not seen a definition for the coefficient of restitution which applies to a two dimensional collision.

Comment: @R.W. Bird For two dimensional motion, it is ratio of velocity of object before collision along common normal and velocity of object after collision along common normal.

Comment: I don't think that we can assume that the rebound angle will be the same as the incident angle.  Also, how do you define "common normal"?

Comment: Common Normal is the line perpendicular to common tangent and passing through centres of both circles. Rebound angle will be same as incident angle because normal reaction(Force that makes ball rebound)between ball and wedge is perpendicular to surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true that for calculating the speed of the individual elements of the system moments after the collision the gravitational forces can be neglected. Since gravity did not have the time to have an effect.

But the normal force from the ground can not be its effect is much more appreciable. When the ball hits the incline the incline gets a velocity component in the Y-axis But it is immediately decelerated to zero. Thus the force must be so large that we can not ignore its effect.$$\frac{dp}{dt}=F,dt\approx0$$ $$F \to \infty$$

Therefore even for that small interval of time, the force changes the momentum of the system significantly and thus not conserved about the Y-axis.

In subjectively simple terms the normal force is more of an external force than gravity moments after the collision.